# What is different in the .NET (c#) implementation of webclient versus java or firefox RESTClient?

Tags: c#, .net, http, visual-studio-2012

I need to post JSON to a https endpoint using c# .

I am using System.Net.WebClient (or HttpWebRequest ).

When I post the JSON to the endpoint using JAVA or the firefox RESTClient everything works fine (from the same machine).

With Wireshark I can see that the receiving server RESETs the connection, resulting in this .NET exception:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I don't use any proxy servers.
I have set the request timeout to -1 (and other values).

What can the .NET runtime be adding to (or removing from) the requests that the firefox RESTPlugin en JAVA are not ?

There must be a difference.
Fiddler shows me two http(s) requests with response status 200, but no data seems to be coming back (and Fiddler introduces a proxy...)

Comment: Look at the request in Fiddler and see what differences you can spot?

Comment: @EdBayiates I didn't down-vote nor close-vote, but I can see what's wrong with this question: it is a duplicate of a gazillion other questions about `connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`.

Comment: @HighCore, if you could post a link to an example dup?  The current close vote doesn't claim it's a dup.

Comment: @EdBayiates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+host

Comment: I known it is a combination of the client and the server, when I point my code to another server this error does not occur. But I don't control the server, so I have to fix it in the client.

Comment: @HighCore, that's just a general search.

Comment: I am aware of the other questions on the connection was forcibly closed. But as I mentioned, the answers there I tried (like timeout settings)

Comment: Comparing fiddler: The response via RESTClient is larger than the one via .NET .
.NET client

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 18:55:21.320
Connection: close
EndTime: 18:55:21.383
ClientToServerBytes: 127
ServerToClientBytes: 0

Comment: Fiddler RESTClient :
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 18:53:01.397
Connection: close
EndTime: 18:55:00.080
ClientToServerBytes: 1623
ServerToClientBytes: 4235

This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
To view the encrypted sessions inside this tunnel, enable the Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic option.

A SSLv3-compatible ServerHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
SessionID:..
CompressionSuite: NO_COMPRESSION [0x00]
Extensions:
  renegotiation_info 00

Comment: @mpjjonker Copy-Paste your tests and trials in an [Update] section too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mason thanks for making me look once more at the fiddler data.

After setting the protocol to TLS1.2

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

It works. 
I have seen posts that actual get an error message hinting at the minimal TLS support. But here I had to go through StackOverflow first.
Just the exercise of formulating the question and the first quick responders helpt me fix this quickly !